# How can I use css to make a row of boxes that do not wrap when browser shrinks?

Tags: html, css, row

I apologize if this is a debug my code question or already answered and I could not find it, I saw many similar things that I couldn't get to work.

I would like to create a page like:

```
A  B  C  D

-----
```

footer

such that when I shrink the browser window, it does not produce

```
A B
C D

----
```

footer

A,B,C are all in a div, D is a table because I couldn't control the width with the sharing code I put in there.

In my understanding that if I do:

```css
#container {
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 900px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.A {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}

.B {
  float: left;
  width: 355px;
}

.C {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}

table.D {
  float: left;
}

hr {
  clear: left
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="simple.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <h3> Commentary</h3>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="A">
        <img src="images/A.JPG" />
      </div>
      <div class="B">
        comments in B
      </div>
      <div class="C">
        <img src="images/C.JPG" />
      </div>
      <table class="D" width="150">
        <tr>
          <td> share </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </article>
  <hr> closing statements.
  <footer> footer stuff.
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

It will work.

One thread I looked at suggested not floating, but if I go to fixed, the elements seemed to stay in the window, regardless of how far I scrolled down.  When the browser shrinks, I want scroll bars for the `A B C D` row to appear.

Sometimes, I boil things down to a simple example like this, and it works, and it is little things like taking the space out of something `float: left` to `float:left`, or removing the 'p' tag that I had to separate the `container` from `hr`, but then when I change my original code, I still have the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap` to make this happen.

*HTML:*

```
<section id="wrapper">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <table></table>
    </div>
</section>
```

*CSS:*

```
#wrapper {
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* Optional overflow-x:hidden */
}
#wrapper div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #BFFF00;
}
```

And, of course, here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2KF7/).

Comment: Thanks! I got it working this way. I had some sections within the div's and I had to set white-space back to normal so their text would wrap again. Now it looks great! Should I have been able to get it working the way I posted? Thanks for the jfiddle link, I had not see that.